# filter the records between json files

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two json inputs, the first one having node and second one is just json based array. I want filter the input json with Id node where elements exists in reference json(it is a key or value array).
Input JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "birds-group",
    "type": "group",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "Birds Types",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "Flying Birds",
            "children": [{ "id": "Parrot" }, { "id": "Crow" }]
          },
          { "id": "Non-Flying Birds", "children": [{ "id": "Peacock" }] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "animal-group",
    "type": "group",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "animal types",
        "children": [
          { "id": "Vegan Animals" },
          { "id": "Amphibians" },
          {
            "id": "Forest Animals",
            "children": [{ "id": "Lion" }, { "id": "Tiger" }]
          },
          { "id": "Domestic Animals", "children": [{ "id": "Cow" }] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Reference JSON:

```
{
  "Birds Types": {
    "Flying Birds": ["Parrot", "Crow"],
    "Non-Flying Birds": ["Peacock"]
  },
  "animal types": {
    "Vegan Animals": [],
    "Amphibians": [],
    "Forest Animals": ["Lion", "Tiger"],
    "Domestic Animals": ["Cow"]
  }
}
```

I need the following output:

```
[
  {
    "id": "birds-group",
    "type": "group",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "Birds Types",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "Flying Birds",
            "children": [
              { "id": "Parrot" },
              { "id": "Crow" },
              { "id": "Sparrow" }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "Non-Flying Birds",
            "children": [{ "id": "Peacock" }, { "id": "Emu" }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "animal-group",
    "type": "group",
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "animal types",
        "children": [
          { "id": "Vegan Animals" },
          { "id": "Amphibians" },
          {
            "id": "Forest Animals",
            "children": [{ "id": "Lion" }, { "id": "Tiger" }]
          },
          {
            "id": "Domestic Animals",
            "children": [{ "id": "Cow" }, { "id": "Dog" }]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried in couple of ways but it doesn't work. I have tried in recursive way also.

```
function filterChildren(children, reference) {
  return children.filter(child => {
    if (child.id in reference) {
      if (child.children && reference[child.id].children) {
        child.children = filterChildren(child.children, reference[child.id].children);
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
}

function filterData(data, reference) {
  return data.map(item => {
    if (item.id in reference) {
      if (item.children) {
        item.children = filterChildren(item.children, reference[item.id].children);
      }
      return item;
    }
  }).filter(item => item !== undefined);
}
```

Comment: what were your attempts?

Comment: Step 1. `JSON.parse` the JSON, so you deal with objects instead of strings - but yeah, show what you've tried

Comment: Updated with my code

Comment: In your desired output, where did the additional children items come from? As an example - `{ "id": "Emu" }`  and `{ "id": "Sparrow" }` in the Birds group.